# Toggle a table <tr>'s display:none using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I would like to use JavaScript to make a table row's `display:none;` and show it again on a click of a button.

Comment: You want to hide all tr's with 3 columns or hide a tr that just happen to have 3 columns?

Comment: hide a tr that just happen to have 3 columns and on clicking a button make the row visible again.

Comment: I updated your question with the changes from your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plain JS - delegation, can handle dynamically inserted rows

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === "A") {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop click
      var  rowId = tgt.getAttribute("data-id"),
        rowIndex = tgt.getAttribute("data-index"),
             row = rowId ? document.getElementById(rowId) : // id passed 
      document.getElementById('table1').rows[rowIndex - 1]; // idx passed
      if (row) row.style.display = (row.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <a href="#" data-id="row3">Toggle row with ID row3</a> | 
  <a href="#" data-index="2">Toggle 2nd row</a><hr/>
  
</div>

<table>
<tbody id="table1">
<tr><td>row 1 cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2</td><td>row 1 cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2 cell 2</td><td>row 2 cell 3</td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td>row 3 cell 1</td><td>row 3 cell 2</td><td>row 3 cell 3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Plain JS - inline handler can ALSO handle dynamically inserted rows but the above is preferred

```js
function toggle(row) {
  if (isNaN(row)) row = document.getElementById(row); // id passed
  else row = document.getElementById('table1').rows[row]; // idx passed
  if (row) row.style.display = (row.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none';
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="return toggle('row3')">Toggle row with ID row3</a> | 
<a href="#" onClick="return toggle(1)">Toggle 2nd row</a><hr/>

<table>
<tbody id="table1">
<tr><td>row 1 cell 1</td><td>row 1 cell 2</td><td>row 1 cell 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>row 2 cell 1</td><td>row 2 cell 2</td><td>row 2 cell 3</td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td>row 3 cell 1</td><td>row 3 cell 2</td><td>row 3 cell 3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you make this for dynamic content?

Comment: @edward Not sure what you mean? If you pass it a row number or ID it will access it regardless of how or when the row was created

Comment: @mplungjan - I was able to resolve the issue, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the [**`style`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) attribute of the element:

```
// `rowElement` is a reference to the row you want to hide
rowElement.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

This vanilla JS solution works (http://jsfiddle.net/C5g8U/3/):

```
tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  if (tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td').length == 3) {
    tr[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

I'm a bit rusty with my vanilla JS, as I use jQuery for things like this, so here's a jQuery solution:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
  $('tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').length == 3) {
      $(this).toggle();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you have no idea, why posting it as answer. Create a fiddle, test it and post.

Comment: It is not toggling and it did not matter that the cell count was 3 or not - see his comment and my edit

Comment: OP said: **hide a tr that just happen to have 3 columns and on clicking a button make the row visible again.**. I didn't care for the button, but this toggles.

Comment: The jQuery does, the plain doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<tr>` an id and then you can hide it with jQuery:

```
<tr id="sampleRow">
</tr>

$("#button").click(function () {
    $("#sampleRow").toggle(); 
});
```

Toggle will make it hidden if it is currently visible, and will show it if it is currently hidden.